# Why does this python function return None

Tags: python, return-value

Here is the function:

```
def genWords():
    global wordsList; global current_char; global char_seq_cords; global current_sequence

    current_sequence = "%s%s" % (current_sequence, getChar(current_char))
    testable_prefixes =  map( lambda x: ["%s%s" % (current_sequence, getChar(x)), x], possible_chars() )
    valid_seqs = filter(lambda x: linguisticly_possible_seq(x[0]),
                        testable_prefixes)  # 2 length list with char seq and char cords second

    for i in valid_seqs:
        if (u"%s" % current_sequence).lower() in english_tree:
            wordsList.append(current_sequence)
        current_char = i[1]
        char_seq_cords.append(current_char)

        genWords()

    if not valid_seqs:
        wordsList.append(current_sequence)
        return wordsList
print genWords()
print wordsList
```

I would expect the output from `print genWords()` to be a list, instead it is `None`. The reason I am so confused is because the final line `print wordsList` prints the expected output; additionally, if I insert this line, `print wordsList`, right before `return wordsList`, I again get the expected output. I can't seem to figure out why the function returns None?

The src here if you need reference:
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1okYiW3jIkZF8HDwpU5Efx32HHkl1hlqcFj0lP6Io0oY/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Because `valid_seqs` is empty?

Comment: You only return a value when "not valid_seqs" is true.  Make sure all paths return something.

Comment: Because an empty value is false in python

Comment: This code may not go to this statement `if not valid_seqs:
        wordsList.append(current_sequence)
        return wordsList` and function doesn't return anything that why result you got is None

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only reach the return statement (thus returning your words list) if `valid_seqs` condition is met.

Otherwise, the function "simply returns", with the default `None` value.

Notice that, in this case, what is being returned is not your empty list (which would definitely *not* be equivalent to `None`). Instead, `None` is what every function gives back if you don't specify another return value.

Answer (score 1):

`if not valid_seqs` will return `False` if `valid_seqs` is an empty list. `gen_words` returns `None` because you have not defined any return value if `valid_seqs` is empty.